# virus infection & task manager

Tags: windows, virus, task-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

For some time, my Task Manager is greyed out when I right click on the taskbar. It's even not shown in the list when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>. Is this some sort of virus?

Rather than installing an antivirus, are there other ways I can fix this situation? I've tried running different process monitors and killing any unknown processes but they just won't stop.

What are the smart solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to install an antivirus as a learning excercise or something similar.

If you're using ProcessExplorer, turn on `Verify Image Signatures` under `Options`. Then add `Company Name` as a column. Processes with no company name are very suspicious.

Check out [this post](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/forum/windows-xp/33333-how-enable-task-manager-again-windown-xp-3.html) to see how to enable it again.

It's worth noting that I found that link in less than a minute using Google.

Answer (score 0):

I would just install an antivirus. [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security_essentials/default.aspx) does a great job, is lightweight, it's free, and comes straight from Microsoft. You could try and take care of it yourself but if it is a virus, you wouldn't be sure if it was gone or not, it could just replicate the files that you deleted.